# Taking print of a particular div using jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Is it possible to print a particular div in a page to print using jquery? If so how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this. http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1591-Ask-Ben-Print-Part-Of-A-Web-Page-With-jQuery.htm